# augmenting bst - is there exist pair (a,b) of numbers such that |b-a| = d?

Tags: binary-trees

How to check if exist pair $(a,b)$ of numbers in BST such that $|a-b| = d$, where $d$ is given.
Example:
contain of tree: $1, 4, 5, 3, 8, 45, 532$
$d=5$,
answer: $yes$, there is pair $(5,8)$
$d=52$
answer: $no$.

I can solve it when number are in array - then I sort them, and in linear time I can find that pair. Neverthelress I can't idea how to augment BST in this task.
Can you give me a hint ?

Answer (score 2):

By "in linear time I can find that pair" I assume you are using two-pointer technique, that using 2 pointers to traversal the array, trying to reduce the gap to the target by advancing one of the pointer.

An in-order traversal of BST outputs all values in order in linear time. So you can apply your linear-time algorithm similarly on BST, only the pointers advancing to the in-order next node.

Comment: Ok, I understand you, but pesimistic time is O(n). Is there solution in O(logn) ?

Comment: You can use interval tree if it is working

Comment: A BST might well be linear, if the elements were inserted in say, increasing order.  So, if you can't find a linear-time solution for an array, you can't find one for a BST.

Comment: even point query in balanced BST is just like binary search in sorted array. (possibly with additional cumulative properties). I don't think this helps to find an O(logN) query algorithm.

Comment: one possible direction may be to store difference between adjacent values in segment tree. then the range sum query is just the difference between two values in orginal. But I haven't got any sub-linear time solution from this.

Comment: Like interval three, changing bounds to be distances it helps. But I started to dislike hit-and-run hinting.

Comment: Ok, tell me more, please. What's possible solution in O(logn) time ?